# what Size and resolution of Images required to place it in navigation bar for iPhone 5s or IPhone 4s?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview

I used (320 * 44) pixels image size in navigation bar but seems blur in iPhone 5s or iPhone 4s?

Using code is:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_Img.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Anyone Please suggest me, what Size and resolution of Images which is easily fit in navigation bar for iPhone 5s or IPhone 4s?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think ul be using it for retina , so use @2x images for them ....

Answer (score 1):

This is a [design cheat sheet](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2) for iOS developers.

If it's blurry that means you need to provide retina resolution image by doubling the size and put @2x at the end of the file names. Check out [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

the standard navigation bar is 320 X 44 but put double dimensioned image, it does not get blur
i.e. by appending it "@2x". that means put image of 640 X 88 named "nav_Img@2x.png";